# #define macro doesn't identify the 2nd bit set

Tags: c, macros, bit

I have a macro for logging purposes. Its code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define BIT_IS_SET(mask, bit) ((mask) & (1 << (bit)))

typedef enum {
    LOG_STDOUT = 1 << 0,
    LOG_STDERR = 1 << 1,
    LOG_FATAL  = 1 << 2
} LOG_FLAGS;

#define QLOG(flags, fmt, ...) \
    do { \
        int use_stderr = BIT_IS_SET(flags, LOG_STDOUT) ? 1 : 0; \
        int is_fatal = BIT_IS_SET(flags, LOG_FATAL) ? 1 : 0; \
        FILE *fdesc = (use_stderr == 1) ? stdout : stderr; \
        if (use_stderr == 1) { \
            fputs("STDERR: ", fdesc); \
        } else { \
            fputs("STDOUT: ", fdesc); \
        } \
        fprintf(fdesc, "[%s]:%d: "fmt"\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        if (is_fatal == 1) { \
            fputs("aboring...", fdesc); \
            fflush(fdesc); \
            abort(); \
        } \
        fflush(fdesc); \
    } while (0)

int main() 
{
    int x = 6,y = 7;
    QLOG(LOG_STDOUT, "x=%d, y=%d",x, y);
    QLOG(LOG_STDERR, "x=%d, y=%d",x, y);
    QLOG(LOG_STDOUT | LOG_FATAL, "x=%d, y=%d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Its first param is bit flags (`LOG_STDOUT` or `LOG_STDERR`) showing where to print (`stdout` or `stderr`). These flags can be combined with `LOG_FATAL`, which shows that `abort()` must be called. In the test code given in the `main()`function, this `LOG_FATAL` isn't recognized as set. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why are you abusing macros? Good luck with debugging and maintenacne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s because the & operator considers all the bits.

```
#define BIT_IS_SET(mask, bit) ((mask) & (bit))
```

You don´t need the do/while, brackets are enough.

Consider:

```
#define BIT_IS_SET(mask, bit) (!!((mask) & (bit)))
```

Better use a function rather than a macro.  The macro may bloat the resulting executable while a function can be re-used.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here:

```
typedef enum {
    LOG_STDOUT = 1 << 0, //becomes one
    LOG_STDERR = 1 << 1, //becomes two
    LOG_FATAL  = 1 << 2  //becomes four
} LOG_FLAGS;
```

Your test code checks if bit four is set. In the macro expansion of BIT_IS_SET you test against `1<<LOG_FATAL` which evaluates to 16:

```
int is_fatal = BIT_IS_SET(flags, LOG_FATAL) ? 1 : 0;
```

Write this:

```
    int use_stderr = (flags) & LOG_STDOUT; \
    int is_fatal = (flags) & LOG_FATAL; \
    FILE *fdesc = use_stderr ? stdout : stderr; \
    if (use_stderr) { \
        fputs("STDERR: ", fdesc); \
    } else { \
        fputs("STDOUT: ", fdesc); \
    } \
    fprintf(fdesc, "[%s]:%d: "fmt"\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
    if (is_fatal) { \
        fputs("aboring...", fdesc); \
        fflush(fdesc); \
        abort(); \
    } \
    fflush(fdesc); \
```

There is also something mixed up with LOG_STDOUT and LOG_STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what your macros expand to:

```
BIT_IS_SET(flags, LOG_FATAL)
```

expands to

```
((flags) & (1 << (LOG_FATAL)))
```

and `LOG_FATAL` is equivalent to `1 << 2`, so this is

```
((flags) & (1 << (1 << 2)))
```

which is

```
((flags) & (1 << 4))
```

but when call QLOG with `LOG_FATAL`, you're passing `1 << 2` not `1 << LOG_FATAL`